# Bootstrap collapse not working when ul class created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

When ul and a tag is created dynamically collapse of a tag not working. code is below :-

```
folderName += folderName = "<li class=\"list\">" +
  "<a href='#' onClick='getRequirementFolderlist(\"" + data[i].foldername + "\");'><i class='fa fa-folder'></i>" + data[i].foldername +
  "<span class='fa arrow'></span></a>" +
  "<ul class='nav nav-third-level'  id ='" + folderList + "'></ul></li>";
     }
   prevFolder = nextFolder;
}
$("#requirement-list").html(folderName);
```

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide functional example that people can use to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize the collapse after putting the html dynamically.

See this code below

```
folderName += folderName = "<li class=\"list\">" +
  "<a href='#' onClick='getRequirementFolderlist(\"" + data[i].foldername + "\");'><i class='fa fa-folder'></i>" + data[i].foldername +
  "<span class='fa arrow'></span></a>" +
  "<ul class='nav nav-third-level'  id ='" + folderList + "'></ul></li>";
}
prevFolder = nextFolder;
}
$("#requirement-list").html(folderName).collapse();
```

Comment: I am using bootsrap 3 and jquery 3.2 it throws collapsible() is not a function

Comment: Okay then use collapse instead of collapsible, i've updated my code

Comment: collapse also didn't work. Bootstrap internally was using metis menu js $('#side-menu').metisMenu();. This helped me.